# Local Instance Issue With Mach-II

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, mach-ii

I'm running mach-ii v1.8 on my local machine with CF10 installed on Win7. I copied a site down from production (which works) and is throwing an error of which I am unable to search for much help on.

Expected structure key - received .; StructGet cannot be executed.

The error occurred in **/web/frameworks/mach_1_8/caching/strategies/TimeSpanCache.cfc: line 413**

Called from /web/frameworks/mach_1_8/caching/strategies/TimeSpanCache.cfc: line 233

```
411:    <cffunction name="getStorage" access="private" returntype="struct" output="false"
412 :       hint="Gets a reference to the cache data storage.">
413 :       <cfreturn StructGet(getScope() & "." & getScopeKey()) />
414 :   </cffunction>
```

The best source I found was [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mach-ii-for-coldfusion/DE7QRaHtwzY/JhAWqz5E_9QJ) thread, but my MACHII_APP_KEY has no punctuation in it. Ideas?

```
<cfparam name="MACHII_APP_KEY" type="string" default="expoadmin" />
```

Comment: Does your production site use CF 10? I found a reference to an issue with StructGet related to app key having a dash ("-") in it. If that's not your problem, have you tried using the 1.9 version of Mach-II? They might have fixed this error in there.

Comment: Production and my system both use CF10. I will try to upgrade my local instance of Mach-II and hope all the current dependencies don't freak out.